# How to auto resize a UIButton by its text in IOS 7?

Tags: ios7, uibutton, sizetofit

I know [UIButton sizeToFit] does works in IOS 6. But it does not work in IOS7.
So I want to know how to auto resize a UIButton by its text in IOS 7.
I searched on Internet but did not find right answer.
Any hint will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by `[yourButton.titleLabel sizeToFit];`